# Is there any good PowerShell plugin for intellij IDEA?

Tags: powershell, intellij-idea, ide, powershell-2.0

We are developing a product which is written in Java and invoking PowerShell scripts.
Our testing project combines JUnit and PowerShell scripts (thousands of lines).
In order to write scripts we are using another editor and than cut&paste the script to IntelliJ IDEA (and I am not talking about fixing broken scripts). Of-course it is a ridicules way to work.

Is there any plan to develop PowerShell plugin to IntelliJ IDEA?
For our team it is very important and useful.

Answer (score -2):

> Not yet, but there's an XML for syntax highlighting. Installation instructions at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6738#comment=27-2092679

Please voice your question in the JetBrains bug tracker - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6738

Comment: Questions which are asking for off-site resources are not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. The best thing to do is to flag them for closure as off-topic requests for external resources. While you probably intended to be helpful, answering off-topic questions is not helpful for the site. It makes maintaining the site more difficult. From a personal point of view, such answers often end up collecting down-votes. From the point of view of the person who asked this question, it is unlikely that they need an answer 5 years after asking the question.

Comment: While "Not yet" does, technically, answer the question. This should, at best, be a comment.

Comment: (Un)fortunately for SO it has allot of "political" power and a high PageRank, so people use it to "pressure" 3rd parties to take notice...

Comment: @Makyen but SO is considered the sponsored user forum for [tag:intellij-idea] so this becomes a gray area

Comment: No, that does not change what is or is not off-topic. See: [What benefits does a sponsor gain from a sponsored tag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277946)

Comment: Why is your answer in spoiler markdown (i.e. hidden until hovered)? Was this intentional?

Comment: As per the comments above, I wanted to deemphasize the off-site resource. Instead point the OP to the JetBrains forum.